# contruced a $*$-isomorphism between two von neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $p$ is a projection in $M$. Can we contruct a $*$-isomorphism between $M$ and $pMp$?

Comment: What is $pMp$???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: $pMp=\{pxp:\ x\in M\}$. Standard notation in the areas covered by these question's tags.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Of course. I misread "$p$ is a projection on $M$" as saying $p:M\to M$, not $p\in M$. (Is "projection" standard for $p^2=p$ in this sort of context?)

Comment: In this context, "projection" means $p^2=p$ and $p^*=p$ (that is, *selfadjoint idempotent*, or *orthogonal projection*). Can be summarized as $p^*p=p$. Projections of the sort you mention (that act on the algebra) also exist in this context; people care about them when they are contractive (which means they have norm equal to one) and those are called *conditional expectations*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with $M=\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C$ and $p=(1,0)$.

The question is more relevant in the case of II$_1$-factors, and it was been studied already by Murray and von Neumann 80 years ago (the *Fundamental Group*). From the uniqueness of the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor $R$ it follows that $R\simeq pRp$ for all nonzero projections $p\in R$. At the other end of the spectrum, Popa has constructed a II$_1$-factor $M$ such that $M\not\simeq pMp$ for all nontrivial projection $p\in M$.